# problem in command definition

Tags: macros

I have this command defined in my thesis and it works fine, but when I try to include it in some other document it doesn't work (compiler reports the command is not defined). What do I forget to define/include ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\revisionHighlight{True}
\def\revisionHighlightOld{True}

\newcommand{\correction}[2]{% old word, new word
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\revisionHighlight}{True}=0%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\revisionHighlightOld}{True}=0%
        \stkout{#1}\textcolor{red}{#2}%
    \else%
        \ifx&#2&%
            \ignorespaces
        \else
            \textcolor{red}{#2}%
        \fi
    \fi
\else%
    \ifx&#2&%
        \ignorespaces
    \else
        #2%
    \fi
\fi}

\begin{document}
\correction{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the macro for striking out text is called `\sout`, not `\stkout`.

Note you have a couple of bad `%` at the end of lines, namely after `=0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\revisionHighlight{True}
\def\revisionHighlightOld{True}

\newcommand{\correction}[2]{% old word, new word
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\revisionHighlight}{True}=0
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\revisionHighlightOld}{True}=0
        \sout{#1}\textcolor{red}{#2}%
    \else
        \ifx&#2&%
            \ignorespaces
        \else
            \textcolor{red}{#2}%
        \fi
    \fi
\else
    \ifx&#2&%
        \ignorespaces
    \else
        #2%
    \fi
\fi}

\begin{document}
\correction{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd prefer an approach based on `\newif`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newif\ifrevisionHighlight
\revisionHighlighttrue
\newif\ifrevisionHighlightOld
\revisionHighlightOldtrue


\newcommand{\correction}[2]{% old word, new word
  \ifrevisionHighlight
    \ifrevisionHighlightOld
        \sout{#1}\textcolor{red}{#2}%
    \else
        \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
            \ignorespaces
        \else
            \textcolor{red}{#2}%
        \fi
    \fi
\else
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
        \ignorespaces
    \else
        #2%
    \fi
\fi}

\begin{document}
\correction{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The macro for striking out depends on which package you use. I have used \stkout instead of \sout (if I remember right) because it works also in math mode. Your code works, thank you, but I would like to understand why mine does not ...

Comment: Furthermore I had to add the % characters on purpose to avoid some funny spacing effect in the case that any of the 2 parameters is not given

Comment: @dario In your example you only loaded `ulem`, if you think `\stkout` is defined by some other package, then you need to load that package. It might even be defined by the class you used for your thesis, assuming you used some custom class.

Comment: I am an idiot. I was convinced \stkout came with ulem but I have defined that. Solved